# iAd testing ADBannerViewDelegate bannerViewActionDidFinish:

Tags: ios, testing, iad, adbannerview

i would like to try to test `bannerViewActionDidFinish:` after a click-through is complete.

my experience is that when testing with the fake ads in a debug-build or on the simulator.  has anyone been able to successfully test this?

`bannerViewActionShouldBegin:willLeaveApplication:` is always called with `willLeave == NO`, and when one clicks on the test iAd, the confirmation appears telling me that iAd is set up correctly … but after closing that window, `bannerViewActionDidFinish:` is never called.

further info:  the iAd banners all show up and disappear correctly in testing, and they are in the app store distribution build and function just fine … up to the point that the user comes back from a click-through operation.  i want to use `bannerViewActionDidFinish:` for this, but i can't see a way to test it with fake ads.

here's the pertinent code (hopefully anyone helping does not need to see the layout code; it appears to always do the right thing in terms of presenting or hiding the iAd banner based on whether the ad is loaded in the banner or not, or whether a generated error occurs or not, and also matches the corresponding log output; the only thing that isn't happening is that `bannerViewActionDidFinish:` is never called during testing:

```
#pragma mark - ADBannerViewDelegate implementation
#pragma mark @optional

#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED > __IPHONE_4_3
// This method is invoked when the banner has confirmation that an ad will be presented, but
// before the ad has loaded resources necessary for presentation.
- (void)bannerViewWillLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    if (banner == self.adBannerView)
#if DEBUG
        NSLog(@"(%@)bannerViewWillLoadAd", self.navigationItem.title),
#endif
        banner.hidden = NO;
#if DEBUG
    else
        NSLog(@"== banner that will load ad is different than this view's banner ==");
#endif
}
#endif

// This method is invoked each time a banner loads a new advertisement. Once a banner has
// loaded an ad, it will display that ad until another ad is available. The delegate might
// implement this method if it wished to defer placing the banner in a view hierarchy until the
// banner has content to display.
- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView*)banner {
#if DEBUG
    NSLog(@"(%@)bannerViewDidLoadAd: bannerLoaded==%d",
          self.navigationItem.title, banner.isBannerLoaded ? 1 : 0);
#endif
    if (self.view.window)
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            [self.view setNeedsLayout];
            [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        }];
#if DEBUG
    else
        NSLog(@"(%@)bannerViewDidLoadAd: window not visible, skipping …",
              self.navigationItem.title);
#endif
}

// This method will be invoked when an error has occurred attempting to get advertisement content.
// The ADError enum lists the possible error codes.
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView*)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
#if DEBUG
    NSLog(@"(%@)%@: bannerLoaded==%d",
          self.navigationItem.title, error, banner.isBannerLoaded ? 1 : 0);
#endif
    if (self.view.window)
    {
        banner.hidden = !banner.isBannerLoaded; // can't say NO, in case banner loaded w/error!
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            [self.view setNeedsLayout];
            [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        }];
    }
#if DEBUG
    else
        NSLog(@"(%@)%s window not visible, skipping…",
              self.navigationItem.title, __FUNCTION__);
#endif
}

// This message will be sent when the user taps on the banner and some action is to be taken.
// Actions either display full screen content in a modal session or take the user to a different
// application. The delegate may return NO to block the action from taking place, but this
// should be avoided if possible because most advertisements pay significantly more when
// the action takes place and, over the longer term, repeatedly blocking actions will
// decrease the ad inventory available to the application. Applications may wish to pause video,
// audio, or other animated content while the advertisement's action executes.

- (BOOL)bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView*)banner willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave {
    return YES;
}


// This message is sent when a modal action has completed and control is returned to the
// application.  Games, media playback, and other activities that were paused in response to the
// beginning of the action should resume at this point.

- (void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    // all new code, to be tested
    [self configureView];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        [self.view setNeedsLayout];
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```